# How can I increase the font sizes used by the WordPress visual and HTML post editors?

Tags: options, post-editor

When I'm editing a post, the text looks too small. I want larger text **while editing**.

Note that I'm **not** referring to increasing the text in the resulting post ... I mean the text *as it is displayed while I am editing*, only.

I've looked at Settings under "Writing" and I see I can change the *number of lines* in the editor to make the edit area larger to fill more of my screen, but how can I make each of those lines render in a larger font?

Answer (score 2):

Put this on the top of your functions.php file after the first `<?php`

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post.php', 'my_admin_css' );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'my_admin_css' );
function my_admin_css() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
#editorcontainer textarea#content { font-size:130%!important }
</style>
<?php
}
```

> The function will print out the additional CSS on the pages where you write posts only (so it's not loading on every admin page), and applies a font size increase ... adjust as required..
>   [Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-visual-editor-font-size)
>
> The above code will work for *HTML mode*, **for Visual mode**, edit the **editor-style.css**, it's included with the theme .. (it's used to make the Visual editor render text the same as it's shown on front side of your side of your site - you're of course welcome to make changes to that file). 
>   [Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-visual-editor-font-size)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried. It does increase the font size in my HTML editor, but not in my visual editor.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea   Did you edit the `font-size` in the editor-style.css?  That should change the size of the font in the visual editor.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning that. I just came across `editor-style.css` as mentioned here: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/editor-style-wordpress-30.html .. solved my problem. Now I can write without having to squint :-)